# Редиректы https в http с помощью правил htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, https

Есть следующий констракт:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/bitrix/admin/1c_exchange\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
RewriteRule ^(/bitrix/admin/1c_exchange\.php)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,QSA] 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/local/orders/1c_exchange\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
RewriteRule ^(/local/orders/1c_exchange\.php)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Разумеется он не работает, т.к. имеет общий `RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443`
Для двух разных `RewriteRule`. Соответственно будет срабатывать последнее правило. Смысл в том, чтобы по запросам `site.ru/local/orders/1c_exchange.php` и `site.ru/bitrix/admin/1c_exchange.php` эти запросы проходили через `http`, а не через `https`.
Что тут ещё можно придумать?

Answer (score 0):

Сработало вот так:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/bitrix/admin/1c_exchange.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/local/orders/1c_exchange\.php$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```